# Why id values show different outputs when I am using *= and * operators

Tags: python-3.x, list, operators

**python 3.9.1**

```py
m = [15, 20, 25]
print(m, id(m))

m *= 2
print(m, id(m))

m = m * 2
print(m, id(m))
```

I executed this code and the result was

```py
[15, 20, 25] 2375102123456
[15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25] 2375102123456
[15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25] 2375097669568
```

The id value was not changed when I used `*=` operator, while `m = m * 2` was.

What is the difference between these two **id** changes?

Comment: For this `*= 2` operation, you're extending the same list twice hence id is the same. Now for this `m = m * 2` operation,  you first extended the list and then passed a new reference to `m`. That's why this `id(m)` shows a different memory address.

Answer (score 0):

For `m *= 2`, the modification is done **in-place** -- see the documentation for [object.**imul**(self, other)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__imul__):

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, ***=**, @=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation **in-place** (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

This is why `id(m)` returns the same value.

For `m = m * 2`, a new object is created with the value `[15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25]`.
Then `m` refers to this new object.

That is why `id(m)` returns a different value in this case.